# Unity3D 2021，how to add System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll?Or how to use Unsafe.AsRef in Unity2021?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In Unity2021,it removes "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"(But you can still find it in Unity2021 Editor file).But some of my plugins need use code "Unsafe.AsRef",it depends on this dll.How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Embed `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` into your unity project. Refer the below screenshot

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNkaG.png)